# How to update/patch SharePoint Group in Person and Group field using Powerapps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Does any one know how to update **SharePoint Group** in Person and Group field using Powerapps patch function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is, in claims and display name give SharePoint group name

```
Set(SearchGroup,{
Claims: "dev Members",
Department:"",
DisplayName:"dev Members",
Email:"",
JobTitle:"",
Picture:""
});
Patch(TestList,Defaults(TestList),{Title:"Test",PersonField:SearchGroup});
```

**Note:** This logic is for SharePoint Group,I assume for O365 group there is different logic.

Answer (score 0):

When patching people fields, the following properties need to be included:

- Claims
- Department
- DisplayName
- Email
- JobTitle
- Picture

Below articles would be helpful to you:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-default-value-to-person-or-group-field-in-powerapps/

https://www.about365.nl/2018/11/01/handling-sharepoint-lookup-and-people-fields-in-powerapps/

Comment: Hi Michael, the examples you are giving are to patch person in a field person and group field. I want to patch  SharePoint Group in person and group field.